# Call web service with interactive push notification iOS 8

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I am trying to implement interactive push notification in my app. The app successfully received the notification.

When the notification received, I have two buttons on the lock screen.Both of them are supposed to initiate two Webservices

Here is my code in `application  handleActionWithIdentifier`

```
    func application(application: UIApplication, handleActionWithIdentifier identifier: String?, forRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], completionHandler: () -> Void) {


    let aps = userInfo["aps"] as NSDictionary
    let id = aps["id"] as Int
    let notification = Notifications()
    notification.notificationId = NSNumber(integer: id)

    if identifier == "APPROVE"{
        APIManager.sharedInstance.approveApprovalRequest(notification)
    }
    else if identifier == "DELETE"{
        APIManager.sharedInstance.dismissBulletin(notification)
    }
    completionHandler()
}
```

I used

```
 NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request, 
    completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in}).resume()
```

for web service call.

But it returns connection errors.

How can I solve this. Any help appreciated.

EDIT:

This is the error I received in log

```
Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=9 "The operation couldn’t be completed.Bad file descriptor"

UserInfo=0x1552ca00 {_kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=9}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is worked for me.

```
let data = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: response, error: error)
```

Answer (score 1):

It should work if you have turn on background modes you can do this in Capabilities and select Remote Notifications.

**Update**
In multitasking and networking you can get EBADF error if the app is suspended and socket is reclaimed read more about this [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2277/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010841-CH1-SUBSECTION3)

> Note: When your app resumes execution the actual error returned by a socket's whose resources have been reclaimed is purposely not specified here to allow for future refinements. However, in many cases the error will be EBADF, which is probably not what you were expecting! Under normal circumstances EBADF means that the app has passed an invalid file descriptor to a system call. However, in the case of a socket whose resources have been reclaimed, it does not mean that the file descriptor was invalid, just that the socket is no longer usable.

**Hint**: check your implementation of `APIManager.sharedInstance.approveApprovalRequest(notificatio`n)

Comment: I have turned on Background modes and selected Remote notification and Background fetch. but doesn't help